# how to find element by css selector using python / selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to pick up links of youtube channels which are located as below:

```
<a id="author-text" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment- 
renderer" href="/channel/UCUSy-h1fPG1L6X7KOe70asA"> <span class="style- 
scope ytd-comment-renderer">Jörgen Nilsson</span></a>
```

So in the example above I would want to pick up "/channel/UCUSy-h1fPG1L6X7KOe70asA". So far i have tried many options but none work:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/me/Chrome Web Driver/chromedriver.exe')
api_url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQG7m1BFeRc"
driver.get(api_url)
time.sleep(2) 
div = driver.find_element_by_class_name("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment-renderer")
```

but I get the following error:
    InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

I also tried other approaches:

```
div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment-renderer")

div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment-renderer')

div=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment-renderer').get_attribute('href')
```

but no luck.. if someone could please help it would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `find_element_by_id('#author-text')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selectors are invalid:

- `driver.find_element_by_class_name("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment-renderer")`

  *you cannot pass more than one class name to `find_element_by_class_name` method. You can try `driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytd-comment-renderer")`*
- `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment-renderer")`

  *it's not a correct XPath syntax. You probably mean `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment-renderer']")`*
- `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment-renderer')`

  *each class name should start with the dot: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.ytd-comment-renderer')`*

But the best way IMHO to identify by `ID`:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("author-text")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, it almost works, it picks up the user names, for example, in the following : <a id="author-text" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment- 
renderer" href="/channel/UCUSy-h1fPG1L6X7KOe70asA"> <span class="style- 
scope ytd-comment-renderer">Jörgen Nilsson</span></a>  it picks up Jörgen Nilsson but i want to capture  /channel/UCUSy-h1fPG1L6X7KOe70asA ... ?

Comment: forgot to stipulate above, driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-comment-renderer']") is the one that almost works

Comment: @tezzaaa, add `.get_attribute('href')` to extract link

Answer (score 2):

You can use BeautifulSoup in python to get the links in anchor tag having specific class names like `soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'yt-simple-endpoint'})` you can read more here [find_all using css](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all)

Comment: Thanks I will try as soon as I can, im travelling at present